# Reload <head> using jQuery

Tags: jquery, load, element, head

Okay, so I know this is very weird and abnormal and I should probably avoid it, but this is what I want to do.  I basically want to reload every `<script>` in the header through jQuery.  You can use `.load(url+" #element")`, but that's only for elements with an ID not with a tag.

How can I select and reload all the scripts in a document?

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found an alternate solution to the problem and took the long route just to be safe.  Thanks for the answers guys.  Definitely some useful info in here.

Comment: What was your solution? Put it in as an edit to your answer in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, what you're trying to do is load more JS onto the page. How about fetching the contents of the JS file (as a string) using AJAX (with say PHP as the backend) and then executing it on the client side using Javascript's eval() function.

Comment: You wouldn't even need to use PHP, would you? Just GET the JavaScript file.... unless the file is from a different domain, I suppose.

Comment: Oh yeah, you could set the dataType as 'script' in the jQuery ajax call or use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ to fetch the script and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to just re-add every script tag in the head.

```
$('head script').each(function(idx,el){
   var pSrc = $(el).attr('src');
   if (pSrc)
   {
      $('head').append('<script src="'+pSrc+'"></script>');
   }
});
```

I did a cursory test, and it seemd to work fine.

Comment: Quick note btw... if the script has some sort of collision detection, the secondary call may not override the first.

The alternative is to... well, reload the browser because all bets will be off as soon as you try clearing out the globals.